# Typescript dynamic type based on the value of the key 'kind'

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a typescript type that only allows one more property besides its 'kind', and that changes based on the value of the 'kind' key.

I'm aware that this is more or less redoing what JSON already does, but I don't have any say in that.

The following works, but I'd rather work with dynamic types in this case:

```js
export interface TitleComponent {
  kind: 'title'
  title: {
    text: string
    isSubtitle: boolean
  }
}

export interface TextComponent {
  kind: 'text'
  text: {
    text: string
    isBordered: boolean
  }
}

export interface ImageComponent {
  kind: 'image'
  image: {
    name: string | null
    url: string
    thumbnailUrl: string | null
    altText: string | null
    caption: string | null
  }
}

export type Component = TitleComponent | TextComponent | ImageComponent
```

The possible components bundled up (there are many more, this is just to keep it short):

```js
export interface Components {
  title: {
    text: string
    isSubtitle: boolean
  }

  text: {
    text: string
    isBordered: boolean
  }

  image: {
    name: string | null
    url: string
    thumbnailUrl: string | null
    altText: string | null
    caption: string | null
  }
}
```

My typing problem (naive approach that doesn't work):

```js
type AvailableKinds = string & keyof Components;

export interface Component {
  kind: AvailableKinds;
  this['kind']: Components[this['kind']];
}
```

Example Usage:

```js
const t: Component = {
  kind: 'title',
  title: {
    text: 'test',
    isSubtitle: false
  }
};
```

Is this at all possible to achieve with typescript (or do I have to stick to the solution above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use intersections to get the type you want. You can't spread things back out to an interface:

```
type ComponentFor<P extends keyof Components> = { kind: P } & Record<P, Components[P]>
export type Component = {
    [P in keyof Components]: ComponentFor<P>
}[keyof Components]


const t: Component = {
  kind: 'title',
  title: {
    text: 'test',
    isSubtitle: false
  }
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQgFtIlgUBnOAbwFgAoOOGBGAG2AC4aGmnUQMbhRhRkAc158EFAMoBXAEYt2XOIogQOmJFIC+DKQKE9GfY8NESpTGQCFoAEzTBH3DVuA79hswiKY4mp0ZkxImERqImJI4nAAPnBI8mxsNnDyUGyWMZKhzAAW8kSK4QhsAKpZORIJSSlp+ZhsMAAqoCbRtYnJqenYmGAsEEg1sXW9jUwG9DMMMACeYHiEJCPkMABi0AA8AApwHeSOVADWwAsQ6ATEpBsUAHxwALw0cKfIbnAHenAAZHAAErAbBOfYAGhuazIlAA2nsALoPBigSCwZhLFa3dYoF6mPhweGIJDvC5XKF3SgI7irSlbXZ7ZGzWHnS7XWk4mAUBG+BigpAiZg07Ew+CvEJMD5IL4AchUHBl4KMrA43Al5g63DlwBEivSMgUyhVaiwbAowB8swA3EA)

Answer (score 0):

At first you must define every types that you in separate type

```
interface TitleComponent {
    text: string;
    isSubtitle: boolean;
}

interface TextComponent {
    text: string;
    isBordered: boolean;
}

interface ImageComponent {
    name: string | null;
    url: string;
    thumbnailUrl: string | null;
    altText: string | null;
    caption: string | null;
}
```

after that you must define a new type that base on generic choose your specific type

```
type componentProps<T extends "text" | "image" | "title"> = T extends "text"
    ? TextComponent
    : T extends "title"
    ? TitleComponent
    : T extends "image"
    ? ImageComponent
    : object;
```

Now you can use componentProps, like:

```
const title: componentProps<"title"> =  {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. This would make the solution even more verbose having to keep track of "title", "image", and "text" (and all the other kinds) at three places. The nice, succinct solution of the accepted answer is what I was looking for.